# How to configure ADFS to populate SAML Assertion's UserData attribute with Base-64 encoded XML data that contains user details from Active Directory

Tags: saml, adfs

Few of our clients (identity provider) need to SSO using SAML into our application (service provider) wherein if the clients user record does not exist in our system then it gets created via user provisioning process supported by our application. However, to provision the user in our system we need the clients to send the user data in XML payload and the XML payload needs to be Base-64 encoded populated as value for SAML Attribute "UserData".

For ex.:

```
<saml:AttributeStatement>
        <saml:Attribute Name="UserData">
            <saml:AttributeValue xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">                 PGJhdGNoPg0KCTx1c2Vycz4NCgk....WJz</saml:AttributeValue>
        </saml:Attribute>
    </saml:AttributeStatement>
</saml:Assertion>
```

Our clients use ADFS and would like to know how to configure ADFS to populate SAML Assertion's UserData attribute with Base-64 encoded XML data that contains user details from Active Directory?

Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this OOTB.

They will have to write a [custom attribute store](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee895358.aspx).

Comment: Thanks! I will try that option.